# Condition Types extending String Literal

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, string-literals, type-constraints

I want to add a type utility which conditionally should add `T`.

###### See [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/condition-types-extending-string-literal-v8id5?file=/src/Component.tsx)

#### The idea is following:

Something like this: `type IfType<If, Eq, T>`

- `If` is a type of `string literal`, for instance `"Cat" | "Dog"`.
- `Eq` is the extracted string literal of `If`, for instance `"Cat"` or `"Dog"`
- `T` is the type I want to returned if the passed `generic type` is of that specific one.

`T` extends an `object`, but if `Eq` is not `equal` then it returns `Partial<T>`, so that the type still knows the `object` keys (for destructuring).

Something like this:

##### `util.ts`

```
type IfType<
  If extends string,
  Eq extends If,
  T extends object
> = If extends Extract<If, Eq> ? T : Partial<T>
```

##### `otherfile.ts`

```
type Type = 'read' | 'write';

type Props<T extends Type> = { 
  type: T 
} & (
IfType<
  T,
  // This gets the ts(2344) error, and I don't know how to stop it
  "write",
  { descriptionOnlyForWrite: string }
> 
| IfType<
  T,
  // This gets the ts(2344) error, and I don't know how to stop it
  "read",
  { hasRead: boolean}
>);
```

This gives this error:

```
Type '"write"' does not satisfy the constraint 'T'.
  '"write"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Type'.
```

Any suggestions on how to type the helper util type?

*Extra info: How I usually would type this without a utils type, which works as I want*

```
type Type = 'read' | 'write';

type Props<T extends Type> = {
  type: T;
} & (
  | (T extends 'write' ? { descriptionOnlyForWrite: string } : { descriptionOnlyForWrite?: undefined })
  | (T extends 'read' ? { hasRead: boolean } : { hasRead?: undefined })
);
```

Comment: pls provide more examples of what you expect and what you dont

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `T extends Type` and `"write" extends Type` does not imply that `"write" extends T`.  Consider what happens when `T` is `"read"` (as `Props<"read">`); it isn't true that `"write" extends "read"`, so compiler is complaining that `IfType<T, "write", XXX>` might not be valid.

It doesn't look like you really want `IfType<If, Eq, T>` to require that `Eq extends If`.  Assuming you don't want to make `IfType` more complicated, you can just remove the [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on `Eq`:

```
type IfType<
    If extends string,
    Eq, // <-- no constraint here
    T extends object
    > = If extends Extract<If, Eq> ? T : Partial<T>
```

and then the following compiles as desired:

```
type Props<T extends Type> = { type: T } & (
    IfType<T, "write", { descriptionOnlyForWrite: string }>
    | IfType<T, "read", { hasRead: boolean }>
);
```

---

If you really care about expressing a constraint on `If` and `Eq`, you will need to pass that constraint as a separate type parameter `C` to `IfType`:

```
type IfType<
    C extends string,
    If extends C,
    Eq extends C,
    T extends object
    > = If extends Extract<If, Eq> ? T : Partial<T>

type Props<T extends Type> = { type: T } & (
    IfType<Type, T, "write", { descriptionOnlyForWrite: string }>
    | IfType<Type, T, "read", { hasRead: boolean }>
);
```

But I doubt that's really necessary for your use case. After all, `IfType` never actually uses `C` to calculate the output type; it's just a sanity check on `If` and `Eq`.  Unless you have some important reason to do this, I'd just remove the constraint on `Eq` entirely.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=30&pln=14&pc=1#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEARATgexgYQ8KALmiAJbAFIDeAUEnUgQJ4zICSAZgCrMQA8t9QRyQQAHgQjAAJlCSE0ZAOYAaAYLoBRAI7KknEeMkykGAEYArCPAJr1APiQBeJMLETpsjeOLXeHXdoOAPx6SABcSAAKIGgEJCAANrycdtRpgkwsejxOSADkaBAgUnlIAD75AO4KEnkA3On0mciRmDBQyQbuxtwsDs6UDDwR+gC+SABkSAAUtkJcPMm6AETVJBLLuoNS0PAKMHF4APLACYwAYhhoAOo1EBHySkijqer0FRy9fJwrhcWbVCQAAsQFAAEpFKQRUwYDAJIrAZ6vegASga1FG1FAkFgCGQXhghSgUFw+CIpHIVEadGaLgWLH4bzo2C6Rlkj2AKjm9Fchg8SGwqiZSG0rP5gu5dH0bjZJgsVhswv6dLFxi85N8-hFWmCoQi0Vi8SSKTStlpX1yBUhpQqeTWtXRGRyrSwHWlfJ6PGVg2aI2ekxmkrpX2SPF0PyQqzuAO2u32h2AJzOlxudweRCeLyDH3p3zDel+kJjwNBEOK0Nh8JAiKzgjRpoxQA)